# How to change 01/23/2020 11:37:23 PM to ISO dateformat

Tags: hive, hiveql, iso8601

How do I change `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM` to ISO Date format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`.

I have tried a couple of functions like `unix_timestamp` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
beeline> select date_format(cast(unix_timestamp('04/19/2020 09:30:59 AM','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a')*1000 as timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');

+-----------------------+
|          _c0          |
+-----------------------+
| 2020-04-19T09:30:59Z  |
+-----------------------+
1 row selected (0.255 seconds)
```

But, if your own timezone is not UTC then you should probably replace simple `cast(... as timestamp)` with a typecast+timezone conversion via `to_utc_timestamp()`:

```
beeline> select date_format(to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp('04/19/2020 09:30:59 AM','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a')*1000,'EST'),'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');

+-----------------------+
|          _c0          |
+-----------------------+
| 2020-04-19T14:30:59Z  |
+-----------------------+
1 row selected (0.236 seconds)
```

See Hive [Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) for details.